# Django + django-oauth-toolkit: How to Register OpenIdConnect Endpoints?

Tags: django, openid-connect, django-oauth-toolkit

**How can I access OpenId Connect endpoints in a django + oauth environment?**

I'm trying to set up a **Django (3.2.5)** env with OAuth v2 + OpenId Connect using **django-oauth-toolkit (1.5.0)**. I was able to follow the [tutorials](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial.html), which means that I have oauth support. I'm able to get Oauth tokens, and protect endpoints with them.

But when I try to [configure OpenId Connect](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oidc.html), **I'm unable to access** `o/.well-known/...` **end-points, they simply are not registered**. I get a HTTP 404, and the debug page shows that django only knows about  `o/authorize/`, `o/token/`, and `o/revoke-token/`. [OpendId Connect section](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oidc.html#oidc-views) seems to imply I don't need to do anything else but enable OpenId for those views to appear.

My `urls.py` looks like:

```
oauth2_endpoint_views = [
    path('authorize/', oauth2_views.AuthorizationView.as_view(), name="authorize"),
    path('token/', oauth2_views.TokenView.as_view(), name="token"),
    path('revoke-token/', oauth2_views.RevokeTokenView.as_view(), name="revoke-token"),
]

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path('^accounts/', admin.site.urls),
    path('o/', include((oauth2_endpoint_views, 'oauth2_provider'), namespace="oauth2_provider")),
    path('api/hello', ApiEndpoint.as_view()),  # an example protected resource endpoint
    path('api/secret', secret_page, name='secret'),  # requires authentication
]
```

As a part of OAuth config I already

- Added `oauth2_provider` to `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`.
- Added `oauth2_provider.middleware.OAuth2TokenMiddleware` to `settings.MIDDLEWARE`.
- Added `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend`, `oauth2_provider.backends.OAuth2Backend`, `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend` to `settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`.
- Since this is a testing env, `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL` is set to `True`.
- Added `path('o/', include((oauth2_endpoint_views, 'oauth2_provider'), namespace="oauth2_provider"))` to `urls.
- Registered a OAuth client of type **confidential** and authorization grant type **Authorization Code**, no OIDC support for oauth tests, RSA for OIDC tests.

and OAuth is working as expected.

As a part of OpenId Connect I

- Generated RSA private and public key.
- Added an RSA appropriate `OAUTH2_PROVIDER` config into `settings`.
- Set `DEBUG = False` in `settings`.
- Set client algorithm to RSA for OIDC tests.

I didn't register any extra urls, since (i) I don't know what to register and (ii) there's no indication I should do anything else.

Answer (score 1):

The url declaration must be:

```
# Configuration according to tutorial, this should be ommited
#oauth2_endpoint_views = [
#    path('authorize/', oauth2_views.AuthorizationView.as_view(), name="authorize"),
#    path('token/', oauth2_views.TokenView.as_view(), name="token"),
#    path('revoke-token/', oauth2_views.RevokeTokenView.as_view(), name="revoke-token"),
#]

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    # configuration according yo tutorial, which OMITS OIDC
    #path('o/', include((oauth2_endpoint_views, 'oauth2_provider'), namespace="oauth2_provider")),
    # This is the proper configuration, which enables OIDC
    path('o/', include('oauth2_provider.urls', namespace='oauth2_provider')),
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

These can also be overriden and modified as requied.

```
path('.well-known/openid-configuration/', ConnectDiscoveryInfoView.as_view(), name='oidc-connect-discovery-info'),
path('userinfo/', UserInfoView.as_view(), name='user-info'),
path('.well-known/jwks.info', JwksInfoView.as_view(), name='jwks-info'),
```

Add these to URLS.
Import the views like this:

```
from oauth2_provider.views import ConnectDiscoveryInfoView, UserInfoView, JwksInfoView
```

This also requires one to set OIDC as true and set a key if RSA Algo is required.

```
"OIDC_ENABLED": True,
"OIDC_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY": get_private_key(),
```